# override php configuration using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm going straight to the point here.

yesterday I uploaded a simple ci application on my client's server however when I setup the application it gives me error:

> `A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Core Warning
>
> Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/php_openssl.so'
>   - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/php_openssl.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Filename: Unknown
>
> Line Number: 0
>
> Backtrace:`

I've search through this and it says that it has something to do with the php configuration.
so I tried going into the php configuration however the account that my client gave me doesn't have the privilege to edit the configuration. so I search again to see if there's a way for me to override the configuration using htaccess.

so here's what I have come up so far.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
  php_value include_path ".:/usr/local/lib/php"
  php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_php4.c>
  php_value include_path ".:/usr/local/lib/php"
  php_admin_flag engine on
</IfModule>
```

I'm not really familiar with this so please bear with me.

so my question is. how can I override the `include_path` of my php config using htaccess.. thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use the `php_openssl` extensions, whilst you don't have your PHP compiled with `--with-openssl` flag. If you're not `root`, you will probably not be able to do anything with it.

Comment: @Nordenheim I see. so there's no way for me to comment out that part in the php configuration? unless I have a root user.

Comment: I don't think so, no

Comment: @Nordenheim I see.. thanks.. but once, I get the root lvl user can I easily comment out that `include_path` in my php configuration?

Answer (score 1):

`include_path` is for PHP files, when you do a `include` or `require` for PHP code.  Loading extensions is something entirely different.  Try the `dl` function to dynamically load the extension at runtime.  See http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php